# Facebook API: get a 'manage_pages' boolean at login

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-permissions

Is there a graph api call to determine if a user has pages they manage, without explicitly asking for the 'manage_pages' permission at login?

At the moment our users login with the read permission of 'user_friends'. After they accept, we use the LoginManager to try for the publish permission of 'manage_pages'. If the user has no pages, they are still asked for permission to manage their pages which is counter-intuitive and lengthens the login process.

Both the Facebook Login button and Manager seem to disallow simultaneous read and publish permissions so that's not an option either.

We are using the Facebook 4.7 SDK for Android.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, there's no such API.

One pattern that we advise apps to follow is to only ask for publish permissions right before they're needed. That way, users get more context, and are more likely to grant the permission. In this case, you might only ask the user for the "manage_pages" permission if they do some action that indicates that they want to manage a page, and for users that don't own pages, they simply won't use that action.